# Spaces in memoir's section headings

Tags: spacing, sectioning, memoir

I need chapter and section headings without numbers and with any leading spaces ignored (the document is generated by a program - `dblatex`). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ mychapter }
\section{ mysection }
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately while chapter headings come out perfectly, section headings are indented, I assume, by

1. gap between missing section number and the heading text (`\quad`?), and
2. the leading space

While I can try to "remove" the first part of the indent by `\setsechook{\hangsecnum}`, the leading spaces have to be dealt with by manual editing. How can I achieve the same behavior as in chapter headings (no indent, leading space ignored)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, if you do not want numbers, then why don't you just ask memoir not to print them? `\setsecnumdepth{none}`

Second I agree, remove the leading space in your titles, but `memoir` can be recoded to ignore it

```
\makeatletter
\def\M@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7][#8]#9{%
  \ifheadnameref\M@gettitle{#8}\else\M@gettitle{#7}\fi%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth%
    \let\@svsec\@empty%
    \memsecinfo{#1}{}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
  \else%
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    \memsecinfo{#1}{\@nameuse{the#1}}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
  \fi%
  \@tempskipa #5\relax%
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@%
    \begingroup%
      #6{%
      \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M\ignorespaces #9\@@par}%
    \endgroup%
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else%
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi%
      #7}%
  \else%
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax%
     \@svsec #9}%
     \csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
       \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else%
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
       \fi%
       #7}}%
  \fi%
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now! I wonder if there is a reason why chapter's vs. section's headings are processed differently with respect to treating leading spaces.

Comment: very different constructions, as the section are usually much simpler than chapter titles.

Answer (score 6):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides the `\setsecnumformat` command for setting section numbering. This includes the space/gap between the section number and title. Add

```
\setsecnumformat{}
```

to your document preamble. Also remove the spaces in your section title:

```
\section{mysection}
```

Alternatively, if this forms part of an automated output, you can patch the `\M@sect` macro to automatically remove the spaces in front of the section title. Do this by adding the following in your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\M@sect}{\@M #9}{\@M \ignorespaces #9}{}{}
\makeatother
```

See chapter **6 Document divisions** (specifically p 107) of the [`memoir` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) for more information on section formatting.

---

**Edit**: In conversation you mentioned that you actually also use the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in your actual document. And, even though the above solved the problem **without** `hyperref`, it is insufficient for your broader needs. Here's how to fix the problem introduced by `hyperref`, and perhaps some investigative analysis on how one can go about solving such a problem:

The `\patchcmd{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` would search-and-replace `<search>` with `<replace>` in `<command>`. For the sake of completeness, you could use `\typeout{success}` for `<success>` and `\typeout{failure}` for `<failure>` so that you will either see the word `success` or `failure` in `<jobname>.log` after you compile. This will give you an indication of whether or not the patch was successful. The reason for this is that sometimes a patch can do nothing because you patched the wrong part of the command (due to similarities - `\patchcmd` only replaces the first occurrence), or it could do nothing because the command is not patchable.

I modified the preamble to the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter \show\M@sect \makeatother % \M@sect as defined in memoir
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\makeatletter \show\M@sect \makeatother % \M@sect as redefined by hyperref
```

The output in the `<jobname>.log` shows the meaning of `\M@sect` after each issue of `\show\M@sect`. Here's `\M@sect` as defined by `memoir` (of course, since this forms part of the `<jobname>.log`, the spacing/alignment is removed):

```
  > \M@sect=macro:
  #1#2#3#4#5#6[#7][#8]#9->\ifheadnameref \M@gettitle {#8}\else \M@gettitle {#7}\f
  i \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let \@svsec \@empty \memsecinfo {#1}{}{#7}{#8}{#9}\
  else \refstepcounter {#1}\protected@edef \@svsec {\@seccntformat {#1}\relax }\m
  emsecinfo {#1}{\@nameuse {the#1}}{#7}{#8}{#9}\fi \@tempskipa #5\relax \ifdim \@
  tempskipa >\z@ \begingroup #6{\@hangfrom {\hskip #3\relax \@svsec }\interlinepe
* nalty \@M #9\@@par }\endgroup \csname #1mark\endcsname {#8}\addcontentsline {to
  c}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else \protect \numberline {\csname the#1\endcs
  name }\fi #7}\else \def \@svsechd {#6{\hskip #3\relax \@svsec #9}\csname #1mark
  \endcsname {#8}\addcontentsline {toc}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else \prote
  ct \numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname }\fi #7}}\fi \@xsect {#5}.
```

The previous `\patchcmd` corrected the line marked with `*`. This is the meaning of `\M@sect` **after** `hyperref` was introduced:

```
  > \M@sect=macro:
  #1#2#3#4#5#6[#7][#8]#9->\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \expandafter \@firstoftwo \els
  e \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi {\Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto {section*}\setlength 
  {\Hy@SectionHShift }{#3}\begingroup \toks@ {\H@old@sectm@m {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
  {#6}[{#7}][{#8}]}\toks \tw@ \expandafter {\expandafter \Hy@SectionAnchorHref \e
  xpandafter {\@currentHref }#9}\edef \x {\endgroup \the \toks@ {\the \toks \tw@ 
* }}\x }{\H@old@sectm@m {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}][{#8}]{#9}}.
```

Since there's no more `\@M #9` after `hyperref`'s redefinition, the patch doesn't find a match and therefore does nothing. We need to insert `\ignorespaces` before `#9` in the above `hyperref` redefinition of `\M@sect` - again marked with `*`. Therefore, we issue

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\M@sect}{{#9}}{{\ignorespaces#9}}{}{}%
\makeatother
```

to supply `{\ignorespaces#9}` (instead of `{#9}`) to the new `\H@old@sectm@m` macro. As such the patch works, and removed the preceding spaces in front of the section title.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned the documents are generated by dblatex out of files in docbook format. In those source files there are no spaces surrounding the sections/chapters titles. I can put whatever I want into preambula of the generated files but adjusting actual titles would involve figuring out how dblatex processes the corresponding docbook tags in its xslt code.

Comment: @AlexV: You could also patch the code for `\M@sect`. I've updated my answer to include this patch.

Comment: Thanks for the `etoolbox` package! While your patch worked with the sample document, plugging it into (huge) preambula of my actual files did not have any effect. (And I saw the "search pattern not found in replacement text" debug message when I tried `\tracingpatches` from `etoolbox`) The culprit turned out to be `hyperref` package which I neglected to include in the example because I stopped adding stuff from the preambula when I thought I reproduced the problem. Is there any easy way to find out how `hyperref` changes definition of `\M@sect` other than studying its sources?

Comment: @AlexV: I've updated my answer to correct for the introduction of `hyperref`. I also included some discussion behind my solution method which doesn't require so much trying to "study its sources", but using some of the features of TeX.

Comment: Thank you so much for the deep and thorough explanation!